# Rails Excon::Errors::Forbidden - Expected(200) <=> Actual(403 Forbidden)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I'm in my local environment and I'm using carrierwave and fog two upload images and files in separates uploaders.

I'm in my local pc and I will use DigitalOcean instead of Heroku

In my attachment uploader I just have:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 storage :fog

   def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.3.6'
gem 'fog', '~> 1.36.0'
```

Config/Initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
 config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY']
 }
 config.fog_directory = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
```

application.yml (created using figaro)

```
development:
DEV_DB_NAME: archgard_cms_development
DEV_DB_USERNAME: username
DEV_DB_PASSWORD: password
S3_ACCESS_KEY: AKIAJXAY2SZYZYYOH7HA
S3_SECRET_KEY: QAZTM/qYjl/bimDLSiWD7DqvbcyaW38yGTY+4lOSjtEav
S3_BUCKET: various-bucket

test:
TEST_DB_NAME: archgard_cms_test
TEST_DB_USERNAME: username
TEST_DB_PASSWORD: password

production:
PRO_DB_NAME: archgard_cms_production
PRO_DB_USERNAME: username
PRO_DB_PASSWORD: password
PRO_DEVISE_SECRET_KEY: 37f2b350d33b55c6a3b428558da7a48d2f24462d88d90b9b6275ceadcb92ec15ae56a50a0dda06dfa6b564dc489f26a30dd3bdjskjskjsdunnnieujeje
S3_ACCESS_KEY: AKIAJXAY2SZYZYYOH7HA
S3_SECRET_KEY: QAZTM/qYjl/bimDLSiWD7DqvbcyaW38yGTY+4lOSjtEav
S3_BUCKET: various-bucket
```

Amazon S3 Bucket Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::various-bucket"
    },
    {
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::various-bucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

I created the user named: carlos21 in Amazon and I added the AmazonS3FullAccess and  AdministratorAccess too. After I created the user I created the bucket.

I tried even with the superadmin credentials for Amazon.

Comment: Could you share the backtrace from the error? The body of S3 errors like this usually include a more informative message about what in particular is not allowing access. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved.

The issue was this:

In my local environment I had the key and secret in the barsh profile. When I was trying to upload the image, the application variables was responding to that file.

I just deleted the lines and use the ones in the application.yml